# Virtual Sitecore User Group - Budapest #11

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

### Topics

***1. HOW FAR YOU CAN GO WITH JSS***

> There are opinions that JSS is mostly used for simple websites or single-page applications. Find out how our team uses JSS, React, Akamai, and Uniform for creating a tremendous website with millions of users for a tourism agency.

by **Artsem Prashkovich**, Sitecore Solution Architect at Brimit. Sitecore MVP 2018-2020.

***2. EXM NEWSLETTER SUBSCRIPTION, THE COOL WAY!***

> EXM Newsletter subscription is always hard to implement. Customers have individual requirements or want to have a solution which is not out-of-the-box.
> In Version 9.1 Sitecore released the Marketing Preference Center, an easy way to manage your Newsletter subscriptions.
> But somehow Sitecore forgot to offer a proper way how to subscribe to these Marketing categories...
> I want to demonstrate a really cool way to subscribe to this marketing categories by a custom Forms field and a custom Submit action and will then show how you can created segmented lists based on these categories which can be used to send EXM Newsletters.

by **Dirk Schäfauer**, Sitecore Senior Solution Architect at CAMAO IDC GmbH.

The presentations will be held in English. Ask your questions or add your comments to the presentations while it's running. Streaming platform will be chosen soon and you will be informed! RSVP to the event to be up to date!

**When (UTC):** Thursday, September 17, 2020 6:00 PM

**Where:** RSVP to the meetup to join online!

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/272801284/)**

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 7 days